# Nested input tags multidimention array form in Python

Tags: python, django

I try to read multidimentional form input data from HTML. I am not sure how to access the nested input tag data in Django View page.Could someone guide me on this matter?

```
<input   type="checkbox" name="create[1][1]">
<input   type="checkbox" name="edit[1][2]"  > 
<input   type="checkbox" name="delete[1][3]">
<input   type="checkbox" name="create[2][1]">
<input   type="checkbox" name="edit[2][2]"  > 
<input   type="checkbox" name="delete[2][3]">
```

Comment: you can get the data by accessing it. `request.POST.get('create[1][1]')`, is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Form data fully dynamic.So i cant define manually.